# Are there any differences between the personality quizzes in Rescue Team DX and the original Rescue Team games?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-mystery-dungeon-dx

In the Pokémon Mystery Dungeon series of games, you first take a [personality quiz](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Starter_Pok%C3%A9mon_(Mystery_Dungeon)#Personality_Quiz) to determine the Pokémon that the player character will be.

Today, the demo for the newest installment in the series, [Rescue Team DX](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/pokemon-mystery-dungeon-rescue-team-dx-switch/), was released, which is a remake of the original Red/Blue Rescue Team games. As per series tradition, the demo (and presumably the full game) opens with a personality quiz.

Since this is a remake/remaster of Rescue Team, I'm assuming that the DX quiz is mostly copied over from those games, including [the questions and the personality determination methodology](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Red_and_Blue_Rescue_Team_Quiz_Guide). But there could have been alterations made, again because it is a remake. So my question is: **Are there any differences between the personality quizzes in Rescue Team DX and the original Rescue Team games?**

Answer (score 1):

From my recollection of the original, the questions were the same but in the remake it seems like the interview was longer.  The main obvious difference is that in the original, if you didn't like the Pokemon you got matched with, you had to reset the game and redo the quiz as opposed to the remake where you can choose to decline that the Pokemon represents you and choose from the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

I ran through a few times cause thats what I do with these games, gender doesnt matter, questions are the same, and if you get eevee you can pick no and choose out of anyone