# What to answer to obtain each Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon-dx

Nintendo recently announced the remake of Pokemon Mystery Dungeon Blue/Red Rescue Team, called Pokemon Mystery Dungeon DX.

Right now there is a playable demo on the Nintendo eshop. As we have seen, the playable Pokemon are the same as Pokemon mystery dungeon blue/red rescue team.

So I would like to know,
**what answers do i have to give during the personality test, to obtain a specific Pokemon?**

Comment: Important note: The demo is just an "excerpt" of the early parts of the game (everything before the first boss), and save data from the demo can be transferred to the full game when it releases in march.

Comment: Oh nice! Didn't know that, thanks for that note.

Comment: Related: [Are there any differences between the personality quizzes in Rescue Team DX and the original Rescue Team games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362595/143571)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to worry about the questions (at least in the demo).  You can answer it for fun/honestly to see what you would get to have a laugh and if you don't like what you get, there is an option somewhere along the lines of "this Pokemon doesn't represent me" and you can choose which Pokemon you'd like to be.

Just in case you are absolutely looking for a guide here is one for the original game.

Quiz: https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Red_and_Blue_Rescue_Team_Quiz_Guide.

Natures: https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Starter_Pok%C3%A9mon_(Mystery_Dungeon)#Personality_Quiz

Some things have changed but just in case you are unable to choose in the full game, this should help out a little.

Comment: So, no matter what I answer, if I don't like the result, can I choose any of them?

Comment: Yep, the initial Pokemon is purely a recommendation based on the answers. @icortazar

Comment: While this addresses the intent of the question, it would still be nice to know if there is a deterministic result of answering the questionnaire, and if so what the possible results are.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann There are some guides for the original game but I did not want to post them as some things have changed for sure (eevee is no longer locked to female only), and to me, the quiz seemed to take much longer.  I can still add one to make the answer more concise but would advise players to take the quiz legitimately since the end result does not matter any more.