# How to get Charmander as your Pokémon in Red Rescue Team?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon

When the remake of Pokémon Mystery Dungeon came out, I decided to play the original, because I don't have a Switch. On my first try, I managed to get Charmander as my main character. But due to how the game works on my emulator (I'm using the VBA), it didn't save. So I tried again with the intent to add save states this time, and I had a different set of questions, and I would get something entirely different, like Cubone, no matter how many times I reset.
My question is: how do I ensure I get a male Charmander specifically as my character (not as my partner but as the main character)?

Comment: why the downvote? is there something I can do to make the question better?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it's probably due to lack of research. The game has been out for while, and I'm sure there are plenty of resources online.

Comment: so this website should be used as a last resort, rather than a primary info source?

Comment: @BlazingTrio Kinda. We're fine with questions from old games, but we also expect a bit of research first. For a topic like this, where people have analyzed it for a while and it has easily found answers elsewhere online already, a question about it would attract downvotes. Especially since there's already a couple of posts here on Arqade which could lead to the answer. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362770/145980) asks about the DX version, but according to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362595/145980) the quizzes/results are the same in non-DX versions.

Comment: @BlazingHero: No, this site is definitely meant to be a primary info source.  Questions are perfectly allowed even if the answer exists on other sites; the intention is to keep that info alive even if the other sites go down.  I'm guessing the downvote is because you mentioned you're using an emulator.

Comment: ok, understandable. thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this guide (one I have used many times for this game) to find out. There are 50 questions you could be asked and only 9 that will actually be asked. The way to get Charmander is by answering the questions with the 'Hardy (male) or 'Brave' (female) answers, if you don't get some questions that give you the opportunity to be more "Hardy" or 'Brave' than anything else then quit and reset the game.

These are the questions you are looking for for Hardy:

---

Question:     A test is coming up.
How do you study for it?

Answers:        Study hard.
+2 Hardy

---

Question     Can you focus on something you like?

Answers:        Yes.
+2 Hardy

---

Question     When the going gets tough, do you get
going?

Answers:        Yes.
+2 Hardy, +2 Brave

---

Question     There is a bucket. If you put
water in it, how high will you fill it?

Answers:        Full.
+2 Hardy

---

These are the questions you are looking for for Brave:

---

Question     You're going bungee jumping for the first
time.                  Since it's scary, you decide to test the
jump with a doll
And the bungee cord snaps!
Will you still try to make a jump anyway?

Answers:        Yes.
+3 Brave

---

Question     There is an alien invasion!
What will you do?

Answers:        Fight.
Do Question #2b

---

Question    You valiantly fight the aliens
But, you are defeated
An alien says to you
YOU HAVE IMPRESSED US.
IT WAS A PLEASURE TO SEE
JOIN US, AND TOGETHER WE SHALL
RULE THE WORLD.
What will you do?

Answers:         Refuse.
+4 Brave

---

Question     There is a scream from behind a door!
How will you react?

Answers:        Yank open the door.
+1 Hardy, +2 Brave

---

Question     A delinquent is hassling a girl on
a busy city street!
What will you do?

Answers:        Help without hesitation.
+3 Brave OR
Help, even if scared.
+2 Hardy, +2 Brave

---

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gba/929408-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-red-rescue-team/faqs/40329

Comment: why the downvotes? is there something I can do to make the answer better?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but currently, this is a link-only answer; should that link ever break for some reason, your answer will become useless, as OP and any future visitors will have no idea *which* questions are the ones with Hardy or Brave answers, or what those answers are. You should edit your answer to directly include those questions and answers, and keep the link as a source.

Comment: Thank you, have updated the answer with the relevant questions and answers.

Comment: Jesus, that bungee jumping question... Maybe should give a +3 in stupidity instead.

Comment: Haha, or you just really loved that doll and needed it back!